# GHC 7.10.2 Data.Vector.Unboxed conflict with REPA 3.4.0.1

Tags: haskell, vector, repa

I've installed the `Vector` package and `REPA` using Cabal for GHC 7.10.2. Running this program:

```
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as R
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

main = print $ R.fromUnboxed (R.Z R.:. 16 R.:. 16) (U.replicate 10 0)
```

I get the following error:

```
repa.hs:4:53:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘vector-0.10.12.3:Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector
                                    e0’
                with actual type ‘U.Vector a0’
    NB: ‘vector-0.10.12.3:Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector’
          is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base’
              in package ‘vector-0.10.12.3’
        ‘U.Vector’
          is defined in ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base’
              in package ‘vector-0.11.0.0’
    In the second argument of ‘R.fromUnboxed’, namely
      ‘(U.replicate 10 0)’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘R.fromUnboxed (R.Z R.:. 16 R.:. 16) (U.replicate 10 0)’
```

Running `ghc-pkg list | grep vector`, I noticed 2 versions of the vector package:

```
vector-0.10.12.3
vector-0.11.0.0
vector-th-unbox-0.2.1.2
```

I ran `ghc-pkg hide vector-0.10.12.3` and tried recompiling, but the error persists. It seems that `vector-0.10.12.3` already came installed (is it part of Base?) but it didn't expose `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to hide the other version. GHCi seems to be pulling in the *most recent available* version of `vector`, which is *not* the one `REPA` was compiled against. `stack` has a reputation for being good at avoiding these sorts of problems, but in your particularly simple case even `cabal` should be able to figure it out. You may want to set up a Cabal or Stack configuration for your project.